# ASP.NET MVC "update-database" problem. DB not visible in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssms

I have a fairly fresh asp.net project with one model. When trying using the "update-database" command in the Package Manager Console everything goes fine, no errors, but when I go to SSMS I don't see any of my migrations. I tried various connection string combinations, changing SQL Server in VS and in SSMS and still nothing. It seems like the database is sent somewhere else and I don't know where.

Here is my actual Connection String:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server= (LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

Previous Connection String based on the info i got from the SQL Server installer :

```
Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

DbContext :

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

PMC output:

```
> Build started...
>     Build succeeded.
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>           Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.6' with options: None
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>           Executed DbCommand (14ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>           SELECT 1
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>           Executed DbCommand (14ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>           SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>           Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>           SELECT 1
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>           Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>           SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
>           Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>           SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
>           FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
>           ORDER BY [MigrationId];
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
>           No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
>     No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
>     Done
```

Thanks to everyone who can give me an idea where I can go with this.

Comment: You were creating database objects in the master database?

Comment: Did you create any migration before calling update-database?

Comment: @Crowcoder the database is set to default. I know that there are few predefined databases, but on setup i used the "default" option

Comment: @Steve yes, first added a migration then updated the database

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my **old connection string**

```
"Server= (LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

there was no "Database = DatabaseName" declaration, so it went by default to the MASTER database. Because of that I had a hard time finding my migrations.

This is the **solution:**

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database = BulkyBook;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

Now everything works like a charm. Migrations are updated and parsed to the declared database. If a database is not created pre-migration, then it will be automatically created upon using "update-database".